# Oslo top bar navigation drop down not working on sub-sites?

Tags: 2013, navigation, oslo

I can only get the drop-down function of the top navigation bar for Oslo to work on my root site but none of the subsites that I have made. Is this intentional?

What can I do to get drop-down navigation to work on the subsites?

Comment: Can you please share the screen shot for that navigation drop down to understand?

Comment: But it was working (using Oslo), and just like that it stopped. Below is a screen shot of our menu. What's happening now is that whenever we click on a menu item below any of the circled menu items, it takes us to "Site Pages" library, and even if we pick the page then for the appropriate item from the "Site Pages" library, it stays on the same "Site Pages" library (displayed in "new experience" UI). The only time the menu items work is when we switch by clicking on "Return to classic..." at the bottom left of the screen. But as you know, this is only temporary. As soon as you close and reopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean **the drop-down function of the top navigation bar** that is shown below?

[image]

If yes, so you should be aware of this functionality is not working with `Oslo master page` in `Publishing Site` or `Team Site` with `SharePoint Server Publishing` feature enabled!

**Note:** you can only find auto generated drop-down for the `list` and `recent` as shown below, but you can't create your own drop-down!

[image]

Meanwhile, It's working properly in **Team site** that **hasn't ever had publishing features enabled** by configuring

- `New Heading` in the `Quick Lunch` setting below `Look and Feel` in `Site Setting`.

[image]

Regarding **Why would this function not work when you have enabled Sharepoint Server Publishing?**

It's by design, once you have enabled the Publishing feature the `Quick Lunch` is removed. and in this case,

- You can use `Seattle` Master Page instead as a workaround solution!!
- Or use a Team site that hasn't ever had publishing features enabled.

**Note:** If you need to make sure that try to create a Team site and check it.

Comment: Why would this function not work when you have enabled Sharepoint Server Publishing?

Comment: It's by design, you can open SR with MS to ask them why :) 
 Please don't forget to upvote and set as an answer in case, it answered your question! https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I have no idea if it answered my question because I enabled Sharepoint Server Publishing so I can't check. I don't understand why they force you to enable publishing for certain features that you might need and then prevent you from using features that you might need once you enable publishing.

Comment: bro, you have asked why drop-down not working?  I replied to you the main reason,it is not working with Oslo master page in Publishing Site or Team Site with SharePoint Server Publishing feature enabled!

Meanwhile, It's working properly in Team site by configuring New Heading
in the Quick Lunch setting below Look and Feel in Site Setting.

Comment: When you ask me why again ? I answered it's by design !! if you need more details ask Microsoft! So what else you need to know to can decide it's answer to your quest or not ???!!!

Comment: I didn't ask you why again. Stop spamming the thread. I've told you I can't check whether or not your answer works because I have enabled Sharepoint Server Publishing. Your answer is also contradictory because you say that it does not work in Team Site with Sharepoint Server Publishing enabled but then you say it works in Team Site.

Comment: There is no contradictory, To avoid Confusion, Team Site with SharePoint Server Publishing feature enabled! is different than Team site without enable this feature! once you have enabled SharePoint Server Publishing feature on team site you can't save site as template meanwhile you can use page layout and design manager...etc. so where's confusion?drop-down navigation working with normal team site that you didn't have enabled SharePoint Server Publishing feature!! Hope it clear now, and don't hesitate to ask if you need further clarification !!!

Comment: I have updated the answer to avoid confusion and to be helpful for future visitors !!